# Having a color, convert entire image to shades of that color

Tags: python, opencv

I want to convert the below sample code to a function which will get as input any pixel color, and re-color whole image using shades of the input color, so it will leave the impression of the image with one same color. I don't know how this technique is named, maybe somebody will suggest and will show how this can be done if it is even possible. How to do that in Python ?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

src = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(src.shape)

# extract blue channel
blue_channel = src[:,:,0]

# create empty image with same shape as that of src image
blue_img = np.zeros(src.shape)

#assign the red channel of src to empty image
blue_img[:,:,0] = blue_channel
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to colorize the image in Python/OpenCV. Convert to gray, then create a 1D LUT using black, blue (or any other color) and white. Then apply the LUT to the gray image.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.merge([gray,gray,gray])

# create 1D LUT
# create 1 pixel blue image
black = np.zeros((1, 1, 3), np.uint8)
white = np.full((1, 1, 3), (255,255,255), np.uint8)
blue  = np.full((1, 1, 3), (255,0,0), np.uint8)

# append the 3 images
lut = np.concatenate((black, blue, white), axis=0)

# resize lut to 256 values
lut = cv2.resize(lut, (1,256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# apply lut to gray
result = cv2.LUT(gray, lut)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_blue2.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to colorize the image in Python OpenCV. Convert to gray, then multiply by a blue (or any other color) image.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
gray = gray.astype(np.float32)

# create blue image
blue  = np.full_like(img, (255,0,0), np.float32) / 255

# multiply gray by blue image
result = cv2.multiply(gray, blue)
result = result.astype(np.uint8)

# save result
cv2.imwrite('lena_blue1.jpg', result)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: But how I convert the image to the shades of the pixel I chose, for example I chose pink color and want the images to look pinky, in shades of pink color. We have only 3 color channels if it is RGB, but pink is (255,20,147), how I convert the image in shades of pink?

Comment: My approach can use any color in place of blue. For pink, replace `blue  = np.full_like(img, (255,0,0), np.float32) / 255` with `pink  = np.full_like(img, (203,192,255), np.float32) / 255` and replace `result = cv2.multiply(gray, blue)` with `result = cv2.multiply(gray, pink)`